# elasticsearch HDFS Repository Plugin install

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to install elasticsearch HDFS Plugin.
The elasticsearch version is 6.3.2.
Hodoop did not.

When you try to run the plugin

`./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ./repository-hdfs-6.3.2.zip`

-> The following error appears.

```
Commands

list - Lists installed elasticsearch plugins
install - Install a plugin
remove - removes a plugin from Elasticsearch

Non-option arguments:
command              

Option         Description        
------         -----------        
-h, --help     show help          
-s, --silent   show minimal output
-v, --verbose  show verbose output
ERROR: Unknown plugin ./repository-hdfs-6.3.2.zip
```

and i also run

`./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install repository-hdfs`

-> The following error appears.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: artifacts.elastic.co
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.urlExists(InstallPluginCommand.java:325)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.getElasticUrl(InstallPluginCommand.java:292)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.download(InstallPluginCommand.java:248)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:210)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:48)
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: can you try  ./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///path/repository-hdfs-6.3.2.zip

Comment: i  tried ./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///usr/local/ELK/elasticsearch-6.3.2/plugins/repository-hdfs-6.3.2.zip
,, but i got 
`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load plugin descriptor for plugin directory [repository-hdfs-6.3.2.zip]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/local/ELK/elasticsearch-6.3.2/plugins/repository-hdfs-6.3.2.zip/plugin-descriptor.properties: Not a directory`

Comment: Possibly the plugin you have downloaded is not proper, can you download it again from different source

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the correct repository-hdfs version:

```
wget --no-check-certificate  https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/repository-hdfs/repository-hdfs-6.5.1.zip

bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///XXX/repository-hdfs-6.5.1.zip
```

please choose your repository-hdfs's version:

```
wget --no-check-certificate  https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/repository-hdfs/repository-hdfs-X.X.X.zip
```